# SVG gradient URL not playing well with <base href>

Tags: html, svg

In a JavaScript / HTML5 web app, I use this in the head of the page:

```
<base href="{My base URL}">
```

to make sure all calls to assets - images, etc. - resolve correctly regardless of any current address set via JS (pushState, etc);

However, this doesn't seem to play well with SVG styles:

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black" stop-opacity="0" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue" />
        </linearGradient>
        <style type="text/css">
            <![CDATA[
                .my-element {
                    fill: url(#Gradient);
                }
            ]]>
        </style>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

The element never gets the gradient fill, because the URL has been affected by the base href.

Comment: This seems to be more of a statement than a question. What response are you looking for?

Comment: The question is how to add a gradient fill when there's a base href in the page, because I cannot.

Comment: Make the URL an absolute URL

Answer (score 0):

Just use an absolute URL.  For example:

```
.my-element {
    fill: url(http://www.example.com/myapp.html#Gradient);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this successfully? It doesn't work for me. I tried putting it in the CSS, and in the fill attribute, but no luck.

Comment: Apologies - rookie error - I thought I could provide an absolute url to another location and save the SVG there. It works if I just do an absolute to the page I'm looking at.